# Slicing every 5th and 6th element from a numpy row vector

Tags: numpy, numpy-slicing

I have an array like this: `A = ([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16])` and would like to extract every 5th "and" 6th element from this row vector, leading to `B = ([4,5,9,10,14,15])`.

I know how to extract every 5th element: `B = A[::5]` but not how to extract two values after one another.

Comment: Shouldnt that be `[ 4,  5, 10, 11, 16]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way using numpy:

```py
import numpy as np
A = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16])

ids = np.ravel(np.array([np.array([4,5]) + i * np.array([5,5]) for i in range(3)] ))

A[ids]
array([ 4,  5,  9, 10, 14, 15])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```py
A[4::5]
```

to get `array([ 4,  9, 14])` and then concatenate and sort with `A[::5]`.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote *every 5th and 6th element*, so I undestrand it the following way:

- divide the source *Series* into "parts", 6 elements each,
- from each "part" take 2 last elements (5-th and 6-th).

So the expected result is (slightly other than you wrote):

- *4* and *5* - 2 last elements from part *0* thru *5*,
- *10* and *11* - 2 last elements from part *6* thru *11*,
- *16* - from the third part (*12* thru *17*) take only *16*, because
  the source *Series* does not contain *17*.

To get just these elements, you can run:

```
pd.concat([s[4::6], s[5::6]]).sort_index().tolist()
```

Details:

- `s[4::6]` - every 6-th element starting from 5-th (note that indexation
  starts from **0**),
- `s[5::6]` - every 6-th element starting from 6-th.
- `concat(...)` - concatenate these 2 results,
- `sort_index()` - restore the original order (assuming that the source
  *Series* has an ordered index),
- `tolist()` - convert the above result (a *Series*) to plain *list*.

For your data sample the result is:

```
[4, 5, 10, 11, 16]
```

**Other possible solution**, this time based on splitting the source *Series*
into parts of size *6* and taking element No *5* and *6* (if any) from
each part:

```
np.concatenate([ tt[4:] for tt in np.array_split(s.values, np.ceil(s.size / 6)) ]).tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build a mask and use the mask to extract the elements:

```
mask = (np.arange(len(A))%6 == np.array([[4],[5]])).any(0)
A[mask]
# array([ 4,  5, 10, 11, 16])
```